# Maven packaging with Docker

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have a Spring project and a corresponding JAR file.

After i change something in one of my Java class files and run `mvn package`, building my Docker image of that project later is using the cached JAR.

Only if i run `mvn clean package`, my Docker build process does not use the cached JAR:

```
Step 4/6 : COPY app/target/app-${VERSION}.jar app.jar
 ---> 19987e6dda16
```

Is that expected?
Do i always have to run `mvn clean package` instead of `mvn package` after changing some code?

Comment: cleaning before packaging makes sure that the previously generated artifact file is not used.

Comment: What do you mean cached jar? Are you using any type of plugins in your pom file that requires you to do a ```mvn clean```. Mainstream plugins technically doesn't require a ```clean``` build cycle. Unless your project requires it or if you change class names the older one can still hang-around in your jar. If you are unsure it always make sense to do a clean package. Or a clean install to put it in your local m2 repo.

Comment: keeping aside the docker build, is your `mvn package` updating your `jar` on the `target` folder?

Comment: @SriniM i actually just noticed that it doesn't.. what could cause this? For some reason i'm getting `Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date` although i'm clearly modifying the code..

Comment: Building from ide?

Comment: No, from terminal.

Comment: @Gambit2007 are you changing the code in IDE and compiling it from terminal or cli?

Comment: Changing it in the IDE and compiling it from terminal.